# What to use instead of this enum?

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, enums

Regarding many references in the network, I've found that using enum in android affects the performance badly. So for simpler `int` or `String` enums, they recommend using an annotation library `@TypeDef`. But what if I have an enum like this?

```
enum class Heroes(
    val heroName: String,
    val heroLevel: Int,
    val healthPoints: Int,
    val xpMultipleMax: Double
) {
    GLAZIER("Glazier", 1, 25, 1.2),
    ONYX("Onyx", 2, 35, 1.3),
    PARDUS("Pardus", 3, 50, 1.5),
    EAGLE_EYE("Eagle eye", 4, 70, 1.7),
    TORNADO("Tornado", 5, 100, 2.0)
}
```

Is it possible to apply the `@TypeDef` here? And I think in this case even `R8` and `Proguard` can't help because as I know they just help to convert the enum to `int`. But how they will convert it to int if I have multiple parameters for each enum?

---

**P.S.** I've created an enum, with a single integer value. Proguard is on, but after decompiling, I see, that it still uses enum under the hood.

```
enum class Heroes(
    val heroLevel: Int,
) {
    GLAZIER(1),
    ONYX(3),
}
```

That's the enum. Now have a look at the decompiled class.

```
public enum Heroes {
   GLAZIER,
   ONYX;

   private final int heroLevel;

   public final int getHeroLevel() {
      return this.heroLevel;
   }

   private Heroes(int heroLevel) {
      this.heroLevel = heroLevel;
   }
}
```

---

***P.P.S Now folks at Google say its okay to use enums*** - [Source](https://youtu.be/IrMw7MEgADk?t=851)

Comment: so is there still a question here ?

Comment: Already no, but I leave it, maybe it will help someone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now use Enums in Android. It doesn't affect that much on performance in ART. It was discussed in the Google I/O You can refer the here in Video [Google IO SpeedLink to Enum topic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IrMw7MEgADk&t=857s)

If you want an alternate for enum in Kotlin, of course, you can always use Sealed classes.

This is how it looks in sealed class

```
 //Enum version
 enum class Heroes(
        val heroName: String,
        val heroLevel: Int,
        val healthPoints: Int,
        val xpMultipleMax: Double
    ) {
        GLAZIER("Glazier", 1, 25, 1.2),
        ONYX("Onyx", 2, 35, 1.3),
        PARDUS("Pardus", 3, 50, 1.5),
        EAGLE_EYE("Eagle eye", 4, 70, 1.7),
        TORNADO("Tornado", 5, 100, 2.0)
    }
    //sealed class verison
    sealed class Heroes(
        val heroName: String,
        val heroLevel: Int,
        val healthPoints: Int,
        val xpMultipleMax: Double
    ) {
        class GLAZIER() : Heroes("Glazier", 1, 25, 1.2)
        class ONYX() : Heroes("Onyx", 2, 35, 1.3)
        class PARDUS() : Heroes("Pardus", 3, 50, 1.5)
        class EAGLE_EYE() : Heroes("Eagle eye", 4, 70, 1.7)
        class TORNADO() : Heroes("Tornado", 5, 100, 2.0) //use 'object' instead of 'class' if you want single instance.

    }
```